# Delete a folder from device internal storage without using adb?

Tags: android

Is there a way to Delete a folder from device internal storage without using adb? I am doing appium automation and I require a clean install every time the test runs.

Comment: ADB or write your tests to clean up after itself

Comment: @cricket_007 can you elaborate bit more?

Comment: You say "without ADB", but I'm saying that is an option. But you might also be able to write the necessary code as part of the tests to ensure the environment is clean